# how to use AsyncTask in Android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'll need to apply AsynTask in my project, And I type like this

```
 private class UpgradeDB(textView: TextView) : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        val innerTextView: TextView? = textView}
```

But I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.eboss.mobilesales.pb, PID: 1596
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter result
                      at com.eboss.mobilesales.MainDBAdminActivity$UpgradeDB.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:21)
                      at com.eboss.mobilesales.MainDBAdminActivity$UpgradeDB.onPostExecute(MainDBAdminActivity.kt:158)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Please attach the entire stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I've updated the latest stack trace @Egor

Comment: the error very clearly, you try to pass null value for non-null variable, where is your parameter `result`

Comment: fixed this problem. Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stack trace points that you're passing `null` for the parameter.

you could add ? to its type:

```
private class UpgradeDB(textView: TextView?) : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    val innerTextView: TextView? = textView}
```

**Edited:**
without your complete codes, but try:

```
 override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: saying the same thing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter result
                      at com.eboss.mobilesales.MainDBAdminActivity$UpgradeDB.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:21)
                      at com.eboss.mobilesales.MainDBAdminActivity$UpgradeDB.onPostExecute(MainDBAdminActivity.kt:158)` @navylover

Comment: @LeonZaii may be need modify onPostExecute

Comment: this is my onPostEcecute `override fun onPreExecute() {
            innerTextView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }`  @navylover

Comment: which line ? @MikeM.

Comment: @LeonZaii AsyncTask onPostEcecute method has a parmmeter, add ? in the end of the parameter

Comment: If I add the `result:String` at the onPreExecute, the override will have a red line wrote  'onPreExecute' override nothing

Comment: @LeonZaii its onPostExecute ,  not onPreExecute

Comment: I've put the `result :String` at the onPostExecute. Still the same @navylover

Comment: @LeonZaii result :String?  , not result :String